# URL helper functions within an Artisan command return empty base URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

When I call any of the url helper functions, e.g

```
URL::asset('foo/bar')
```

from within a command the base URL is an empty string, and the url returned is

```
http://:/foo/bar
```

I am running the command by calling

```
php artisan myproject:MyCommand
```

from a command line. Where MyCommand is a class that extends Illuminate\Console\Command

I have set my url in config/app.php but I only get a fully qualified url when I run from an 
HTTP Request

I am using Laravel Framework version 4.1.24

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have the same problem simply calling the asset() helper directly rather using the facade as both methods end up in the same place. I've tried to reproduce your problem on a clean install for 4.1.24, but couldn't. So there's something else going on here that your question doesn't cover. What environments do you have set up? What have you set your root URL to in your config.php?

Comment: do you get the same problem using URL::action() ?

Comment: yes same issue if I call asset() directly and also URL::action() has the same problem.

The url setting is 'http://mysite.dev' but also tried with localhost with and without http.

I get the same problem if I don't have detectEnvironment set up.

Maybe a case of removing one by all vendor packages I have and see if one is causing this problem.

Comment: also, to be clear - this is happening when I run

php artisan myproject:MyCommand 
from a command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

My artisan file was missing this line

$app->setRequestForConsoleEnvironment();

The file I had was an older version. This line was added Oct 25, 2013

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get `URL::asset('')` from? I don't see it mentioned on [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing)

Try this instead:

```
URL::to('foo/bar')
```

Comment: It's one of the helper functions 

http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls

I have the same problem for URL::to() aswell.