# Laravel 5: How to get config value in artisan console command

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I get config values in Laravel like this:

```
$value = config('app.name');
```

If I try the same in a method, which is called from an artisan command, then I get the following error message:

> [ErrorException]   Trying to get property of non-object

Is it possible to get config values from an artisan console command?

I have found [a solution for Laravel 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22513287/3886962), but there is no such method in Laravel 5.

Comment: Are you try this solution `Config::get('app.name')`?

Comment: Thank you Andrey. It works.

Comment: I very happy. I write this as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config()` helper use application instance and it can be not available in the console. Try this solution `Config::get('app.name')`

Comment: this is the good solution. However I don't find it intuitive that config() doesn't work when working with Console Commands or Jobs